# FreeBSD can't mount home partition

Tags: mount, freebsd, fstab, zfs

I've been having an issue with my first installation of FreeBSD.  As I always do in GNU/Linux I created separate home and root partitions.  The issue I've been having is that my home partition doesn't mount.

Luckily, when boot fails it just dumps me at a root prompt but unfortunately after remounting / as read-write and not just read only, I can't mount /dev/ada0p3, my /home partition, as /home, or as anything else.

The exact error I get is `mount /dev/ada0p3: No such file or directory`, and yet a quick `ls /dev/` shows me that `ada0p3` is indeed there, and `gpart show` confirms that partition 3 on device ada0 is freebsd-zfs and is 185GB, the size I allocated for my home.

I'm using zfs for both / and /home.

This is a fresh install, so if need be I have no qualms with nuking the drive and reinstalling, but I'd prefer to avoid spending more time on this than I have to.

Comment: ZFS mounts are performed using `zfs` command.

Comment: How are you installing FreeBSD? The **Auto (ZFS)** option already creates separate datasets for `/` and `/usr/home` and several others.

Comment: If ada0p3 is type freebsd-zfs then it is likely a member of a zpool, not a directly mountable filesystem.  Please edit your post to include the output of `zpool status` and `zfs list`. While you're at it, throw in `zfs get -t filesystem canmount,mountpoint`. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `zfs mount -a`. If this doesn't work, check the following `zfs get mountpoint,canmount hostjails tank/home` or `tank/usr/home` depending on your pool name and dataset location

**mountpoint** should be defined to a folder like **/home** and **canmount** should be **on**

If that is not the case you can fix it with `zfs set canmount=on tank/home` for example, similarly to mountpoint.

Please ensure the mountpoint folder exists before trying to mount.